# How to search in the source code for a string with php?

Tags: php, html

I have tried

```
<?php
  $url = $_POST['attributename'];
  $needtofind = "did not match any documents.  </p>";
  $site = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/#q=site:$url");
  if(strpos($site, $needtofind) == false) {
    echo 'indexed';
  } else {
    echo 'not indexed';
  } 
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

HTML

```
<div class="center-page">
  <form method="POST">
    <textarea id="float" name="attributename" value=""></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Codes are on the same page. I just typed them like this to be more clear.

Main problem is that by default it tells me on the screen `indexed`. If i type any url it will say as well `indexed`. For example I type the url in the textarea jhbsadhbahsd545.com, it returns `indexed` when it should have returned `not indexed`.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: are you SURE google's "failed" output exactly contains your string? two spaces after a `.` is an oldschool typographic convention that has absolutely no use on the web - two spaces would be displayed as a single one, and google's not going to spend bandwidth to send a space that will never ever be seen.

Comment: @Marc B I have removed the 2 spaces and same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you cannot scrape content from Google that way, they actually prohibit you from doing it. You'll need to utilize their API to do what you're needing.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: Now it returns `not indexed` for all, even if they are indexed.

Comment: If you're going to change exactly **1** character in the op's code, then you should at least point out WHERE that change is.

Comment: It's much appreciated your example.

Comment: Ah, did not noticed this, Thanks will check it.

Answer (score 2):

strpos can return 0 which is a falsy value. Compare with ===

```
strpos($site, $needtofind) === false
```

However I believe this won't work as Google does not return the string with the first response that you are looking for, but rather lazy loading once the page has been loaded with javascript.

Open up Chrome and `view-source:https://www.google.com/#q=site:hopefullythisisadomainthatdoesnotexists.com` to check what does Google return and why is it always missing.

---

Also change the URL you are making the request to from:

`https://www.google.com/#q=site:$url`

to:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=site:$url`

Comment: Good point here, still doesn't do anything. Will see with `curl`.